# Positioning controls in different containers relative to each other

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got the following scenario, where I'd like to position `Button1` right below and horizontally aligned to `Button 2`, but still keep `Button1` in `groupBox1`, whereas `Button 2` is in `groupBox2`:

[image]

I've seen several posts about `PointToClient()` and `PointToScreen()`, but have still not been able to translate correctly between different containers - `groupBox1` and `groupBox2` in this case.

I've tried some variations of the code below (attempting repositioning the buttons whenever the form is resized, for instance), but I'm still confused about exactly how this works.

Specifically, it seems unclear to me which `control` I should call `PointToScreen()` on, and which parameters I should pass to that method in order to achieve what I've described above.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{  
    var btn2Pos = button2.PointToScreen(button2.Location);

    button1.Location = button1.PointToClient(btn2Pos);
}
```

What would be the simplest way to solve this?

> **Sidenote, reason for doing this**: 
>   I want to be able to disable `groupBox2`, and all the controls in it, but still keep certain
>   controls like `button 1` enabled, even though they are positioned
>   relative to `button 2`.

Comment: I am confused `right below and horizontally aligned`. Is the image what should be the end result and both buttons be in same ratio after resizing the window?? Or you are talking about overlapping of buttons?

Comment: No, the image is an example of what it might look like to start with. After repositioning, button1 should appear to be in groupBox2, and just below button 2. The code is not complete - just a part of some of the things I've tried in order to get the buttons positioned in such a way that they would be more related to each other (as opposted to related to their different parent containers).

Comment: I am still not sure with the output you want. But I feel it can be achieved by manipulating Anchor property itself. No need for that much amount of code I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `PointToClient` and `PointToScreen` here:

```
//This will place button1 over button2
button1.Left = groupBox2.Left + button2.Left;
button1.Top = groupBox2.Top + button2.Top;
```

If you want to use `PointToClient` and `PointToScreen`, you can do something like this:

```
//The code should be placed in Form load, if placing in form Constructor, the result may be not expected.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
  //This will place button1 over button2
  button1.Location = groupBox1.PointToClient(groupBox2.PointToScreen(button2.Location));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that last option seems to be more or less what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely just on .Left/.Top properties by accounting for the different relative positions. Example:

```
button1.Location = positining(button1);
```

by calling function on these lines:

```
private Point positining(Button curButton)
{
    Point outPoint = new Point();

    if(curButton == button1)
    {
        outPoint.X = groupBox2.Left + button2.Right + 20;
        outPoint.Y = groupBox2.Top + button2.Bottom - 20;
    }
    else if (curButton == button2)
    {
        outPoint.X = groupBox2.Left + button1.Left - 20 - button2.Width;
        outPoint.Y = groupBox2.Top + button1.Top + 20 + button2.Height;
    }

    return outPoint;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was what I wanted to avoid, as in my real application, things are a little more complex, and there may be several layers of containers, making such a calculation a little messy.

Comment: These kind of implementations might become difficult (mainly under complex situations), but they deliver undoubtedly the most reliable performance. But well... it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answers here, but ended up using the following solution at the end, as proposed by a collegue:

I created another, third container, but this one without a border. That container overlaps `groupBox2` exactly, and `button1` is positioned within that container, and therefor relative to it.

Since the point (0 , 0) of the new container overlaps with the equivalent point in `groupBox2`, any controls with the same coordinates in either container, will be positioned at the same place, and all I need to do is make sure to call `BringToFront()` (and/or `SendToBack()` if needed) to make sure the control is displayed correctly.